# different image size makes layout look uneven

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap. When i add image which is bit larger than other images then my div sizes doesnt look even. I am not sure how to fix it. Here is the code

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9" style="">
<div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-4 " style="">
        <div class="relative">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
            <div class="tip">
             <h3><a href="#">Test block1</a></h3><div class="text">
<em><a href="#">AAAA</a></em>   
            <p>Test paragraph 1</p>
        </div></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-4 " style="">
        <div class="relative">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
            <div class="tip">
             <h3><a href="#">Test block 2</a></h3><div class="text">
<em><a href="#">BBBB</a></em>   
            <p>New paragraph</p>
        </div></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="  col-md-4 " style="">
        <div class="relative">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
            <div class="tip">
             <h3><a href="#" title="Leasingforløpet">New title</a></h3><div class="text">
<em><a href="#">Title block 3</a></em>  
            <p>Paragraph </p>
        </div></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class=" col-md-4 " style="">
        <div class="relative">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
            <div class="tip">
             <h3><a href="#" title="Elgen i baksetet">Title3</a></h3><div class="text">
 <em><a href="http://minleasing.no/category/minleasing/">Title block 4</a></em>

            <p>Paragrpah start</p>
        </div></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class=" col-md-4 " style="">
        <div class="relative">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
            <div class="tip">
             <h3><a href="#" title="Leasing – Et trekantforhold">FFFFFFFFFFF</a></h3><div class="text">
<em><a href="#">GGGGGGGGG</a></em>

            <p>GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG</p>
        </div></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="  col-md-4 " style="">
        <div class="relative">
            <img id="problemImage" class="img-responsive" src="http://minleasing.no/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/refleksdagen1-350x302.jpg" />
            <div class="tip">
             <h3><a href="#" title="Leasingforløpet">Problem Image</a></h3><div class="text">
<em><a href="#">aaagr</a></em>

            <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
        </div></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>    
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><div class="facebook">Facebook Stuff</div></div>
</div>
```

Here is the link to [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pk1pr96n/116/)

If you look in the code is that image with id called `problemImage` causes uneveness

Answer (score 0):

I think what you will have to do in this case, is set a hard height on all the images. (or add a class that has a hard height set, up to you)  You will need to edit the photo to match the selected height, or else it will look all squishy ;)

Notice below, the height property on the img tag is set to 200px.

This forces each image to adhere to this rule, making your site look clean and organized, and prevents any image from being too big or too small.

Updated Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/5tr34k/pk1pr96n/117/

```
                <div class=" col-md-4 " >
                    <div class="relative">
                        <img style="height:200px;" class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
                        <div class="tip">
                            <h3><a href="#">Test block1</a></h3>
                            <div class="text">
                                <em><a href="#">AAAA</a></em>   
                                <p>Test paragraph 1</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-md-4 " style="">
                    <div class="relative">
                        <img style="height:200px;" class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
                        <div class="tip">
                            <h3><a href="#">Test block 2</a></h3>
                            <div class="text">
                                <em><a href="http://minleasing.no/category/leasing/">BBBB</a></em>  
                                <p>New paragraph</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="  col-md-4 " style="">
                    <div class="relative">
                        <img style="height:200px;" class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
                        <div class="tip">
                            <h3><a href="#" title="Leasingforløpet">New title</a></h3>
                            <div class="text">
                                <em><a href="http://minleasing.no/category/leasing/">Title block 3</a></em> 
                                <p>Paragraph </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-md-4 " style="">
                    <div class="relative">
                        <img style="height:200px;" class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
                        <div class="tip">
                            <h3><a href="#">Title3</a></h3>
                            <div class="text">
                                <em><a href="#">Title block 4</a></em>
                                <p>Paragrpah start</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class=" col-md-4 " style="">
                    <div class="relative">
                        <img style="height:200px;" class="img-responsive" src="http://www.imagesfestival.com/images/resize.php?width=350&src=images/news/216.jpg" />
                        <div class="tip">
                            <h3><a href="#">FFFFFFFFFFF</a></h3>
                            <div class="text">
                                <em><a href="http://minleasing.no/category/leasing/">GGGGGGGGG</a></em>
                                <p>GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="  col-md-4 " style="">
                    <div class="relative">
                        <img style="height:200px;" id="problemImage" class="img-responsive" src="http://minleasing.no/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/refleksdagen1-350x302.jpg" />
                        <div class="tip">
                            <h3><a href="#" title="Leasingforløpet">Problem Image</a></h3>
                            <div class="text">
                                <em><a href="http://minleasing.no/category/leasing/">Problem iamge </a></em>
                                <p>Test</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Update - here is a screenshot of the fiddle from above, showing the correct resizing on a smaller screen:

[Resized Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/078IR.png)

Comment: but due to this what happens is that text below image is not properly algined when we resize the window

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, i could not see more than one column on fiddler >< @Happy

Comment: Also, it looks like my fiddler did not save any code !! :C

Comment: @Happy  Here is the correct fiddle.  Please have a look at it and see that when you resize the window, the problematic image is correct and all is well: https://jsfiddle.net/5tr34k/pk1pr96n/117/

Comment: May i know what change you made?

Comment: I dont see any change from your previous code in fiddle. In previous fiddle you had added height 200 px and in this fiddle also the same. So what is change in 2 fiddles?